# Ext JS 4.1 - User-defined validation doesn't bind button

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1

I defined a validation which controls if the id is unique or not to bind a button. It **works well with built-in validations** well, but **it doesn't bind for my own validation**.

Here's what I've tried:

**View - FormPanel:**

```
Ext.define(appName + '.view.user.UserForm', {
    extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',
    requires: [appName + '.view.language.LanguageCombo'],
    alias: 'widget.userform',
    //  title       : 'User Form',
    iconCls: 'icon-form',
    frame: true,
    padding: '5 5 0 5',
    border: true,
    buttonAlign: 'right',
    width: '100%',
    //    height    : 200,
    monitorValid: true,
    bodyPadding: 10,
    fieldDefaults: {
        labelAlign: 'left',
        labelWidth: 110,
        anchor: '98%',
        allowBlank: false,
        selectOnFocus: true,
        msgTarget: 'side'
    },
    initComponent: function () {
        var me = this;


        this.title = bundle.getMsg('userform.title');


        this.items = [{
            xtype: 'numberfield',
            minValue: 1,
            fieldLabel: bundle.getMsg('userform.field.recordId'),
            name: 'recordId',
            itemId: 'recordId'
        }, {
         ];


        this.btnReset = Ext.create('Ext.ux.button.ResetButton', {
            handler: function (btn) {
                me.getForm().reset();
            }
        });


        this.btnSubmit = Ext.create('Ext.ux.button.SaveButton', {
            disabled: true, 
            formBind: true
        });


        this.buttons = [me.btnReset, me.btnSubmit];


        this.callParent(arguments);
    }
});
```

**Controller Method:**

```
var form = this.getUserForm();
if (field.getValue() && field.getValue() != '') {
    Ext.Ajax.request({
        url: 'user/chkRecordIdUnique.ajax',
        method: 'POST',
        params: {
            recordId: field.getValue()
        },
        success: function (response, options) {
            var res = Ext.decode(response.responseText);
            if (!res.success) {
                field.markInvalid(bundle.getMsg('record.taken'));
                form.getForm().markInvalid(bundle.getMsg('record.taken'));
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the docs, `markInvalid` doesn't actually change the validity of a field. It just applies the visual styles as if the field had an error. And there's no `isValid` property to set. All validity is determined by an immediate call to the `isValid` method.

As it stands, Ext JS forms do not support asynchronous validation natively. It assumes that either all validation is done on the client side, or that the server will perform validation. If you want to perform an Ajax call to determine if the form is valid before enabling the save button, I would recommend making your own validate method with a success callback. Manually enable the save button if the Ajax call succeeds and the rest of the form is valid. Then on form change, you can disable the save button again.

Side note: `width` should be a number, not a percentage.

Comment: @Erick Cook thanks for your care but actually this was just a sample of  code. So I have to check other fields too. So I can't enable or disable form bind button manually or I should do this for each user-defined validations; this doesn't make sense..

Comment: If each field can be validated independently you can use synchronous Ajax to perform your validation in the `field.validator` function. Ext JS doesn't support it via `Ext.Ajax.request` so you'd have to do it manually (should be pretty easy to set up). I actually had to do it myself just recently so it's possible. If fields depend on other fields, you should really consider dropping `formBind` and just doing all the validation/enabling yourself.

Comment: ok thanks a lot Eric, it seems I should implement it myself as you did. But it would be better if the core library does it; when a field marked invalid(so form becomes invalid), a button which has formBind:true is also effected.

Comment: Agreed. There's a lot of room for improvement in the form validation process.